# Creating cross site custom columns with a dummy content type

Tags: content-type-hub

As we know if you create a custom content type via the Content Type Hub it will make it available across all site collections.

I like to create a dummy content type to publish custom columns across site collections that are not attached to a custom content type.

Does anyone see a problem with this practice or have a better approach?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why this would not work. If you need columns - without content types - to be available on site creation from the hub I'd say this is the only approach.